# How should you style polynomials where one term is taller than the others?

Tags: mathjax

There's something wrong looking about this equation. Is there a right way to display this? [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/akja31Lr/)

[image]

```
\(
    s^2
    =
    \frac
        {
            \Sigma X^2
            -
            \left(
                \frac
                {\Sigma X}
                {n}
            \right)^2
        }
        {
            n-1
        }
\)
```

Comment: I would like the sigmas a little larger than what they encompass, but otherwise I don't see much wrong. I don't work with mathematical typesetting, though.

Comment: It's not clear what "something looks wrong" means, here.  Can you be more specific about what you think is wrong, and what you think it *should* look like?  If it is the size of the sigmas, as @ArndtJonasson suggests, try using `\sum` rather than `\Sigma`.

Comment: \sum makes the sigma bigger but the X stays the same size and in the same position. You're asking me to define what looking wrong means? Can't you just look at it? I don't mean to be rude.

Comment: I am looking at it, and the screen shot in your post looks perfectly correct to me.  That is why I'm asking you to say what you would like to have changed.  If you are saying that the second sigma and X that is inside the parentheses is smaller than the one outside is the problem, then I would argue that you are wrong.  MathJax uses the layout rules established by the TeX typesetting system (the gold standard for math typesetting), and when a fraction is appears within another fraction, its size is reduced.  This is the correct result.

Comment: You can, however, override that if you must, and use `\dfrac` rather than `\frac` to get a fraction with the size and spacing of a top-level displayed equation.  But I'm just assuming this is what you think the problem is (based on hints in your title and comments).

Comment: It would be great if the TO could answer. Because when I now look over what was written here, I'm also not quite sure what was actually wanted and what is wrong about the current result. Could you make it clear or maybe tell us how you solved it meanwhile?

Comment: Well I don't know how to define the problem precisely. To do that I would have to say something like "the shorter polynomial should be lower by 2px" and then I would know the answer. I just find the way it looks unsatisfactory without being able to fully explain why I feel that way. My answer was to go with it exactly how it is. https://regressionbuddy.com/appendix/statistics > Variance and Standard Deviation